# How to Implement Android-ParallaxViewPager using ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have read on the [github page](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager) for **Android-ParallaxViewPager** about implementing it using ScrollView but I didn't understand what it actually meant! :(

This is what given on the github page -

```
How to implement? see below.
1. Change ListView in NotBoringActionBar to ViewPager.
2. Make ListView or ScrollView of Fragment in ViewPager.
3. Make Interface that Activity can get a Listener when you use OnScroll() in ListView or ScrollView.
4. Make Interface which is available to scroll when some events is happened in ListView or ScrollView.

From now on, you can fix scrollY value in ListView wherever the pages are swiped through the interface you've just made.
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm sure I'm not the only trying to get this working with `ScrollView`.

In its code [kmshack](https://github.com/kmshack) has used an interface with `onScroll()` method accepting `AbsListView view` as a parameter.(for handling the scroll events inside `ListView`)

Does this mean that for `ScrollView` the `onScroll()` method should accept the `ScrollView` for handling the scroll events inside `ScrollView`?
Or a method has to be defined for handling the scroll events?

I'm confused! Please help me.

Comment: did you manage to do the same thing? i am also doing the same part.. i completed NotBoaringActionBar with Tabactivity.. if you finished this task please reply .. for viewpager issue i found this link ..http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2014/05/09/parallaxviewpager-parallax-background-effect-for-the-viewpager/